# Poor FPS in game while streaming

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance, twitch

I have been recently streaming and I have set my stream onto all the best settings for my internet speed and the right resolution etc.

Here is my speed test results (speedtest.net):

[image]

While I stream people say that the stream is really smooth and gameplay looks fine however in game for me I get a terrible FPS! Usually on Medium settings (In Minecraft) I get around 20-70 FPS however I see a MASSIVE drop when streaming which is around 10-30 FPS!?!? Can someone please help me and try and see what I can do to solve this?

P.S I use OBS to stream to Twitch.tv

Comment: What are your system specs like?

Comment: I don't really know too much but I have; ATI Radeon HD 5450 1GB (Graphics Card), Dual Core, idk what CPU or whatever I have... When I bought my PC there were the specs but my dad knows (He is better than me at computer stuff).

Comment: have you tried other broadcasting software or the minecraft feature?

Comment: OBS primarily relies on the CPU for compression and streaming. This is an issue because Minecraft also relies heavily on the CPU for map generation and whatnot. If you want to stream minecraft without lagging I suggest a hardcore processor or a capture card. For future reference,  internet speed does not in any way affect FPS.

Comment: @Ender51 XSplit doesn't have a time-limited trial. It only limits the features. Also, have you tried closing all other programs in your background or broadcast straight from Minecraft? (You have to link your Twitch account with your Mojang account first) - XSplit has been known to take a lot of CPU to broadcast/record, so try bringing down your resolution.

Comment: I have got good CPU but is there any way to make it better rather than just upping the priority because It can burn out the processor if I'm not careful. Also how much approx are new/better processors?

Comment: Yeah, I stream at 720p but at a downscale of 420p... I lag really bad and want to make good quality streams (Like with text, facecam etc.). Can you still do that with the Minecraft streaming thing?

Comment: @Ender51, increasing priority won't burn out your CPU, that's not how it works. However, it will leave your system unstable if you don't know what you're doing. By increasing a program's priority, it will run more often (thus improving its performance), but in return another program won't run quite as often (thus reducing that other one's performance). Like I said, in the worst case this can turn your system unstable.

Comment: @ender51 - CPU's aren't cheap. The minimum intel CPU I'd recommend is the i5-3570 which costs about $200 but I can't guarantee an improvement in streaming performance. Then you also have to consider motherboard compatability. If you can figure out what exact cpu you have I can give an accurate suggestion. For now I assume you have a celeron which could be a 775, 1150, 1155, or 1156 socket. The 3570 typically uses an 1155 so you may or may not have to buy a new motherboard as well if you wanted to use it.

Comment: I am English so it's around £155 which is A LOT!  I don't think I can get that... is there a cheaper one that I could get that is almost as good?

Comment: I can't stream using the Minecraft streaming system because my account is already Migrated and it says that it isn't.... when I go to the only option to migrate it the site says ''You are currently only allowed 1 copy of Minecraft per account.'' So I can't stream that way - At least just for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make this an answer so I can give a more complete and better formatted reply.

First off, keep in mind that most popular streamers usually have a separate computer dedicated toward streaming. This requires a significant investment!

In order to immediately improve your performance you should put minecraft at the lowest possible settings as well as look to reduce the compression ratio of OBS. Higher ratio = more work for your CPU = FPS lag/drops. I'm at work at the moment, but when I get home I could look into it further. Don't worry about burning out your CPU either. The only way that would happen is if youre trying to overclock it or if its just faulty. Feel free to adjust the priority,  just understand that it can negatively impact the performance of other programs including OBS. If you prioritize Minecraft you run the risk of taking processing power from OBS which will cause your stream to lag.

Having a good rig doesn't always guarantee the ability to stream either. I can hit about 200 fps in league on my computer, but if I try streaming I get a considerable performance drop along with a nearly imperceptible delay.

I'll add onto this if anything else comes to mind as my caffeine kicks in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I have all my settings at their lowest e.g Fast graphics and Render distance 4. Even at that I suffer lots of FPS drop. As I said I am terrible at stuff like this so I have no idea especially because I am new to streaming.

Comment: Have you looked into making YouTube videos? There are some screen recording programs that are less intensive on your CPU and will allow for better gameplay.  A personal favorite of mine us Dxtory. I know there are a bazillion Minecraft youtubers/streamers, but if you find your niche and build a following on YouTube you can easily make the transfer to streaming.  This will also allow you to save up money to get a better rig in the future :p

Comment: Yeah, I have started YouTube, I use Fraps but I am thinking of getting Dxtory because of good reviews... What file format do they save as? I have to convert Fraps .avi to .mp4 because they won't upload

Comment: Btw I do lose FPS but not as badly as when I try to stream altough I do enjoy streaming. I have also recently found out that I lag less when I stream my favourite Minecraft Modpack The Crafting Dead (Hence I love The Walking Dead on PC and TV) so maybe I could just stream on that and record everything else.

Comment: Dxtory can actually record directly to mp4 with the x264 codec [link here](http://www.superuser.com/questions/662145/how-do-i-record-in-mp4-file-format-with-dxtory). Personally,  I like capturing in a RAW format (you need A LOT of hard drive space for this) and then converting it to whatever format while watching a movie or something less intensive. This greatly reduced

Comment: Also people do say that Fraps lags more so I will get Dxtory now